# Cannot render objects with any missing geometries: None

Tags: python, geojson

```
for polygon in my_geo_df:
    polygon_json = geo.to_json(polygon)
    geo_poly = folium.GeoJson( polygon_json, style_function=lambda x: {'fillColor': 'blue', 'fillOpacity': 0.4})
    geo_poly.add_to(m)
```

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-220-3abc5e6d00cc> in <module>
      1 for polygon in my_geo_df:
      2     polygon_json = geo.to_json(polygon)
----> 3     geo_poly = folium.GeoJson( polygon_json, style_function=lambda x: {'fillColor': 'blue', 'fillOpacity': 0.4})
      4     geo_poly.add_to(m)

~\Desktop\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\folium\features.py in __init__(self, data, style_function, highlight_function, name, overlay, control, show, smooth_factor, tooltip, embed, popup, zoom_on_click, marker)
    641         self.marker = marker
    642 
--> 643         self.data = self.process_data(data)
    644 
    645         if self.style or self.highlight:

~\Desktop\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\folium\features.py in process_data(self, data)
    688             raise ValueError(
    689                 "Cannot render objects with any missing geometries"
--> 690                 ": {!r}".format(data)
    691             )
    692 
ValueError: Cannot render objects with any missing geometries: None
```

Comment: It's hard to why based on the snippet of code you've provided but it looks like for some reason `polygon_json` has a value of `None` for at least one item in `my_geo_df`.

Comment: Could you add the complete script or module you're working on?